# Custom printf without va_list

Tags: c

I am trying to create a simplified version of printf() but without the use of va_list, va_start, va_arg and va_end.

My original idea is to have:

> > void my_printf (char *format, ...);

Then, go through the format, and count the number of % (arguments) to find out how many variables were passed to my function. From there, I was thinking of creating a buffer based on how many arguments there are, then combine then and use write() to finally output them.

Is there a better way of approaching this problem? Will I run into issues with my plan?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Some of my brainstorming code is:

```
// Count arguments
int cnt_s, cnt_c, cnt_d, cnt_u, cnt_x;
for (; *format; format++) {
    switch(format[0]) {
        case '%':
            switch(format[1]) {
                case 'd':
                    cnt_d++;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You **need** `va_list`, `va_start`, `va_arg`, and `va_end` to access the arguments specified by the `...`

Comment: I was thinking of accessing them directly from memory. What would I use besides `...` then?

Comment: That's a hilariously bad idea. **Why** are you trying to circumvent the standard means provided for accessing variable length argument arrays?

Comment: Its not for any practical applications.

Answer (score 4):

You **need** `va_list`, `va_start`, `va_arg`, and `va_end` to access the arguments specified by the `...`

Unless you want to use `void*` and unions ----- UGH!

Comment: Pass an array of unions to your function (the `void*` thing was a brain fart) ... but you really want `va_arg` and friends!

Comment: If I could use va_list and what not I would, but I am unable to in this case. The function will be called using my_printf(format, arg1, arg2, arg3, ect). How would I grab those args without using va_list and what not? I was thinking of using the format var which is provided regardless as the starting memory location, then count the number of args listed in format, then with that, hop around memory from the starting location(format) and grab each variable.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: `my_printf_d(format, intval)`, `my_printf_f(format, doubleval)`, `my_printf_dddfd(format, intval1, intval2, intval3, doubleval, intval4)` ...

Comment: @Pat: What you describe is quite precisely what va_start and friends do for you in a portable way.

Answer (score 3):

The best way I can think of to do this (NOTE: this is potentially unsafe) would be to take the address of the format string and increment from that to find the arguments.

Heres a working example I hacked together (assumes implementation of other print functions)

```
int my_printf(char *format, ...) {
    void *beg = &format;
    int i;
    beg += sizeof(char*);
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(format); i++) {
        if (format[i] == '%') {
            switch (format[i+1]) {
                case 's':
                    print_s(*((char**)beg)); 
                    beg += sizeof(char*);
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    print_d(*((int*)beg)); 
                    beg += sizeof(int);
                    break;
                case 'f':
                    print_f(*((float*)beg)); 
                    beg += sizeof(float);
                    break;
            }
            i++;
        } else {
            putchar(format[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This could potentially cause some unintended side effects if you dont provide enough arguments, and it might require some tweaking. But thats the idea.

Explanation:
This works because all function arguments are shoved on the stack in order. So since you have the first argument (the format string) you can take its address and increment according to the desired argument to directly access the arguments on the stack without any VA_ARGS magic.